# QMake not finding GraphicsMagick libraries

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake, graphicsmagick

I am trying to link a Qt program with GraphicsMagick, but Qt/qmake refuses to search `/usr/local/*` for GraphicsMagick++-config. I am using the `$$system()` command to fetch the flags like so:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$system(GraphicsMagick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags)
QMAKE_LIBS += $$system(GraphicsMagick++-config --ldflags --libs)
```

But every time, qmake complains `/bin/sh: GraphicsMagick++-config: command not found`. I have tested my path, and I can see `/usr/local/bin` from sh, csh, zsh, and bash. I am not sure why Qt can't find this command. Is there something simple I am missing?

I am running OS X 10.9, with Qt 5.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you run qmake from the same shell where you did the PATH test, running it through a Finder-launched QtCreator might not inherit the environment if you set it in your ~.*shrc file.

I tried your code and qmake properly calls `GraphicsMagick++-config` with my brew installed GraphicsMagick.

FWIW, even though you might get the same error, a better way to get it to work would be to let qmake figure out the pkgconfig logic itself:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG = GraphicsMagick++
```